# Proving a function one to one function from the given function

Tags: functional-equations

Here is the  function, $$f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}, f(f(m)+f(n))=m+n$$. This is a one to one function.
But I cannot proceed further. I have tried to arrange the domains and their respective ranges, like,

$f(f(3)+f(1))=4 \land  f(2f(2))=4$.

But cannot proceed further.
Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: What exactly do you have to prove ?

Comment: To prove that this function is injective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking $m=n$ in the assumption $f(f(m)+f(n))=m+n$, we get 
$$\tag{1} f(2f(n))=2n\mbox{ for all }n\in\mathbb{N}.$$
Now, if $f(m)=f(n)$, multiplying it by $2$ and then consider its value under $f$, we get
$$f(2f(m))=f(2f(n)),$$
which implies that $2m=2n$ by $(1)$, which gives $m=n$. This proves that $f$ is injective.